# Match numbers which contain a character, using C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get matches from strings which have a letter 'A' in the middle of a number sequence with specifically 16 characters.

Example inputs and expected outcomes:

> A4921000A05034816 => 4921000A05034816
>
> 4921000A05034816 => 4921000A05034816 (the same, 16 characters, 15 digits and an 'A' in the middle)
>
> 4921000405034816 => 4921000405034816

I have attempted the following regex:

```
@"[0-A-9]{16}"
```

In the first case it is matching the first A even though is not in the middle of the sequence, which is not correct.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: just `"\d[0-9A]{15}"` (or if you prefer `"[0-9][0-9A]{15}"`) should do (be careful if there can be 2 As and you don't want those strings though)

Comment: There are many regexs that will match your requirements. Like `\d+A?\d+` Give more instructions if you want a more accurate regex

Comment: You can use `^A?(?=[\dA]{16}$)\d+A?\d+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\d[\dA]{14}\d
```

This will match a 16 character string that starts and ends with a digit and has digits and letters `A` in the middle. (Allowing 0 or more `A`s)

Answer (score 0):

Okay gonna try my hand at this regex, no promises.

`((A)?[0-9A]){16}`

There are a million and one websites out there that can help with regex

> https://www.regexpal.com/

Is my favourite

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to get the last 16 characters (need confirmation). If I'm right, you just need the end delimiter for your regex.

Using PCRE will be `.*([0-9A]{16})$`. Maybe the end delimiter for C# is not `$`

Comment: Your regex syntax is the same in most regex engines and is valid in C#. Here's [Microsoft's C# regex documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks for the link @ctwheels !

Answer (score 0):

This regex works for you examples:

```
\d{7}(A|\d)\d{8}
```

If 'A' is on 8 position always.

And:

```
[\d][\dA]{15}
```

If 'A' can be anywhere but not in first position

Comment: Using `[A\d]` is faster than `(A|\d)`. Also, you don't need to use `[]` around `\d`

Comment: 'A' should be anywhere but not in first or last position.

Comment: In this case it will be look like: [\d][\dA]{14}\d